# PHP error in shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

Can anyone help me see the error in this code?  I'm trying to implement a function via shortcode which I found [here](http://www.supercreatives.co.uk/2012/12/add-wooslider-php-to-your-index-template/):

```
<?php if (function_exists(‘wooslider’)) echo do_shortcode(‘[wooslider slider_type="posts" limit="3" link_title="true" layout="text-bottom" overlay="full" category="homepage-feature-post"]‘); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using proper syntax, so you are likely getting a syntax error. You are using some strange sign in your code where you should be using a single quote (`'`). Also, use curly brackets to enclose a condition. It is easier to debug

```
<?php 
    if(function_exists('wooslider')){ 

echo do_shortcode('[wooslider slider_type="posts" limit="3" link_title="true" layout="text-bottom" overlay="full" category="homepage-feature-post"]'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a stack Pieter.  I couldn't see the wood for the trees - the original had some weird quotes I didn't notice.